# Android Retrofit only connects when using emulator

Tags: android, retrofit

I've a local server in my computer, I want to make requests usin Retrofit, there's no problems if I use the android emulator I've no problems making the requests, but when I try to use it in my android device (and changing the ip to the one that shows when I type ipconfig)

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="escoladeltreball.org.decaught">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".TutorialActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RolSelection"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

API INTERFACES:

```
public interface SOService {

   @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api-auth/")
Call<Token> get_token(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

APIUtility class as

```
public class ApiUtils {

    //I use this one with Android emulator

    /*public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";*/
    //I use this one in my android phone, the ip is obtained from  ipconfig
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.104:8000/"



    public static SOService getSOService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SOService.class);
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient as :

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();



        if (retrofit==null) {


            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And finally, call the function as following

```
private void signIn() {
    boolean isValid = validate();
    if (isValid) {

        mService.get_tokken(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Tokken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Tokken> call, Response<Tokken> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println("Te lo imprimo");
                    System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "tokken recibido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Tokken> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error al recibir tokken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And the error I get:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.104 (port 8000) from /192.168.43.208 (port 40695) after 10000ms
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
                  at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:71)
                  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
                  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
                  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
                  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
                  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
                  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
                  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
                  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
D/MainActivity: error loading from API
```

Comment: There's not a lot to go off here, but my assumption is the local server on your computer is only available to your computer, and not exposed anywhere...even to the local network. I would try searching for configurations for whatever server tool you are using, and figure out how to configure it for what you're wanting to accomplish, or start running the server in a web environment. This is definitely not a Retrofit/Android issue.

Comment: your device and your server MUST be in same network

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with Android or Retrofit but with the server, the server didn't allow external connections.

@WoogieNoogie was right!